# Jquery Datepicker selected date to Next week or two week

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wanted to make the Jquery Datepicker selected date to be the next week from current date, I tried it , but did not got luck. And also about the time picker I wanted to be something selected like 10:00Am.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: what time picker plugin do you use? please post link

Comment: Do you mean that you want to restrict user to select dates which are one week ahead of current date ? If you post some code, it will be easy to answer.

Comment: @naveen I am using this plugin http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/#d-demo-wrapper-2

Comment: @KutePHP, no I just wanted something like, when DatePicker opens, today's date is selected, I want to make selected date one week later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't get the specifics about the `selectedDate` inside your `datepicker` and I prefer using a diferent time of `timepicker`.
The Timepicker plugin & demo: [Adding a Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

If you use this, you can easily achieve all your requirements like this.

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: '+7d',
    ampm: true,
    hour: 10,
    minute: 30
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle with working example](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/vdtyk/4/).